# Trouble loading node_modules in Intellij idea ultimate

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I am able to get up and running with nodejs by following the steps in this tutorial
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/11/webstorm-your-node-app/

However, I am not able to load any modules while running through the ide.  The debugger just blows up at the line

```
express = require("express");
```

Please note that I have all the modules installed locally(node_modules directory under root of project directory) and not globally.
FYI, I am able to run the same from the command prompt, just not through intellij.

Please note, I am using node 0.6.6.  I am running on Ubuntu 11.10 x64.

Thanks
-Venu

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion how you may proceed.

First let me describe the problem, then the workaround, then the proposal to get this addressed.

### Problem

Blow up at require("express")

### Reason

1. By default intellij will suspend upon any exception.  See the breakpoint rule.
2. You got stuck at the exception.
3. The exception, in this case, is due to the fact that module.js is trying to resolve the "express".  It actually forms different paths and filenames (see logic in module.js, starting line 159).
4. Because not all permutations of paths and filenames formed properly, exception is thrown at fs.statSync() fs.js 414 just because that path/filename does not exists.

### Workaround

Turn off break at all exceptions when startup/loading modules.  Turn it back on when your server is running.

### Proposal

next iteration of node.js library handles package/module resolution more elegantly?  Let me see if there's a bug being filed already.